# Laravel won't use my subject line for emails

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am trying to set a subject line for an email but Laravel keeps using the class name "FormCompleted" as the subject, here's the code I've got:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class FormCompleted extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;

        protected $data;

        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @param $data
         */
        public function __construct($data)
        {
            $this->data = $data;
        }

        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build()
        {
            return $this->subject('Form submitted')
                ->view('emails.form-completed')
                ->with('data', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1: The problem is only with my local server, it works on my production server

Comment: Try to separate the subject, like this: `$this->subject="whatever"` than call which view to render

Comment: @ka_lin this is not correct; OP has used correct syntax of `$this->subject('whatever');`

Comment: Tried that. it didn't work either. Look at my question I added some extra info

Answer (score 1):

We may need to see the code that is used to implement the `FormCompleted` Mailable class and send the email, and maybe even your email Blade view as well. That would help debug further.

However, I tested out your code, and I got the email sent correctly with the appropriate subject as expected.

The only change I did was to use `->with($this->data)` instead of `->with('data', $this->data);` (how you have it), because, the properties defined within the `$data` object, are what the view uses.

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Testing Email 2')
        ->view('foo.mail2')
        ->with($this->data);
}
```

I would have gotten an error otherwise (with the view trying to use unavailable properties, since the view would have been looking for a `data` property).